# Cannot remove the bootcamp partition whether with disk utility or terminal

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have been trying to remove my bootcamp partition recently. When I run bootcamp assistant, it simply does not recognize the bootcamp partition, and prompts me to create another bootcamp partition.

`diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         180.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         70.7 GB    disk0s3
                    (free space)                         180.3 GB   -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +180.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     138.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 359.7 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      5.4 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            15.5 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 15.5 GB    disk1s5s1
```

I have tried removing the bootcamp partition manually with disk utility, but it tells me that it failed. Now when I try to remove it again, the '-' button is grayed out, like this:
[image: Disk Utility '-' button grayed out]

I have also tried `sudo diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ drive disk0s3`
But the following message appears:

```
❯ sudo diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ drive disk0s3
Password:
Started erase on disk0s3
Unmounting disk
Error: -69879: Couldn't open disk
```

And the error message `Error: -69879: Couldn't open disk` appears every time I try to do **anything** related to the bootcamp partition.

By this time my whole disk is just messed up. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't you find it odd that a 251.0 GB drive has a total of 314.6 MB + 180.0 GB + 70.7 GB + 180.3 GB = 431.3 GB of partitions and free space?

Comment: You can try from recovery mode doing in disk utility a First Aid on the internal ssd then reboot and give the result of `diskutil list`

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes that's what I noticed too. That's why I said my disk is so messed up

Comment: Try posting the output from `for i in 1 2 3; do diskutil info disk0s$i | grep -e Size -e Offset; done`. This will not change your drive. I just want to see where the partitions are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP refers to the the `Microsoft Basic Data` partition (`disk0s3`) as the "bootcamp" partition. This partition can not be removed using the Disk Utility application, because the partition in not the next partition after the `Apple_APFS` partition (`disk0s2`). In order to display correct output, the `diskutil` command often requires the partitions to be stored in ascending in the GUID Partition Table (GPT). In the OP's case, this is not true, which caused the `diskutil list` command to produce the flawed output shown in the OP's question.

To illustrate the problem, I created a sparse disk image which has a partition arrangement similar to the one occurring on the drive described in the OP's question. The identifier assign to this sparse disk image is `disk2`. The output from the command `diskutil list disk2` is shown below.

```
/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +251.0 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     322.2 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         177.2 GB   disk2s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨⁩                        73.5 GB    disk2s3
                    (free space)                         177.5 GB   -
```

Just as in the OP's question, the sum of the individual sizes do not equal the total size. Also in both instances, the output from the `diskutil` command shows the size sum of the first two partitions equals the size of the free space. This is shown below.

```
      OP's Question                My Answer
------------------------    ------------------------
    0.3 GB -> disk0s1           0.3 GB -> disk2s1
+ 180.0 GB -> disk0s2       + 177.2 GB -> disk2s2
----------                  ----------
  180.3 GB -> free space      177.5 GB -> free space
```

Just as in the OP's question, the `Microsoft Basic Data` partition can not be removed using the Disk Utility application. Below is a image of the Disk Utility application showing the grayed out `-` button.

[image]

Since I am using a sparse disk image, I can enter the command `gpt -r show /dev/disk2` while booted to macOS. This command shows the partition location data stored in the GPT. The output is shown below.

> Note: The OP would have to boot to macOS Recovery or from a macOS installer in order to execute a similar command.

```
gpt -r show /dev/disk2
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40  143564800      3  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  143564840     629200      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
  144194040  346040342      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  490234382         32         Sec GPT table
  490234414          1         Sec GPT header
```

The above output shows the partitions are not stored in ascending order in the GPT. The `diskutil` command is incorrectly displaying the first two partition entries as occurring before the third partition entry. Also, the `diskutil` is showing the space occupied by the first two partition entries again as free space occurring after the third partition entry.

---

Since the `Microsoft Basic Data` partition (`disk0s3`) occurs before the `Apple_APFS` partition (`disk0s2`), the space occupied by the `Microsoft Basic Data` partition can not be merged back into the `Apple_APFS` partition. The OP needs to backup important data, erase the drive and reinstall macOS.

### Appendix

The table below show selected equivalents between the types displayed by the `diskutil` command and the GUID partition type value stored in the GPT.

| `diskutil` Type | Partition Type GUID |
| --- | --- |
| EFI | `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B` |
| Microsoft Basic Data | `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7` |
| APFS | `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` |